# How IE load BHO. Does it load BHO with some sequence

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, bho

If there are two BHO which have similar functions, How does IE decide which one to load first? Because the first loaded BHO will affect the later loaded BHO. So I want to set my BHO as the first loaded one. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

There is no documented way to do this. But from my experience the BHOs are loaded in the order of registering them in the registry under the key - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Browser Helper Objects`.

So to make a BHO load before the others, you need to generate a CLSID that appears before the others in dictionary order.

This will however not guarantee that other third party BHOs do not load before yours. You could try to register a BHO with a hand coded CLSID.

Comment: But this behavior is not guaranteed and can change at any time.  And hand coding a CLSID is a terrible idea.